# how to manage both AsynchronousSocketChannel or AsynchronousServerSocketChannel in java

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am writing with Java NIO. My module is going to work like a someone who get some data as a server (with AsynchronousServerSocketChannel) and then it send this data to another completely different connection which created by AsynchronousSocketChannel as a client

```
public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel result, Void attachment) {
        asynchronousServerSocketChannel.accept(null, this);
        try {
           System.out.println("Incoming connection from: " + result.getRemoteAddress());
           //transmitting data
           while (result.read(buffer).get() != -1) {
                  buffer.flip();
                  result.write(buffer).get();
                  ClientwithFuture anotherDiffrentSocketChannel = new ClientwithFuture(buffer);
```

using last line is not logical, because it causes the server interrupted and running the AsynchronousSocketChannel. SO in your opinion what could be a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I define two thread and in one of them I write the AsynchronousSocketChannel and in the other I write AsynchronousServerSocketChannel. for communicating between this two thread I use some shared variables and I solve the problem.